# How can I use google-oauth20 callback to both redirect and send response data?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm using passport.js to authenticate using google. I have both a local strategy (email + password) and google strategy (google authentication):

```
router.post('/login', authenticateRequest, authController.login);

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { 
    scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);

router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { 
    failureRedirect: '/', session: false,}),
  authController.login
);
```

Both the login function, and the google callback functions, after authenticating activate the authController.login method, which creates the tokens and sends the response:

```
const login = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const accessToken = req.user.generateJWT(); // req.user is set by passport
  const refreshToken = req.user.generateRefreshToken();
  const userInfo = req.user.toJSON();
  res.json({ accessToken, refreshToken, userInfo });
};
```

For both local login and google login, the response is sent back as expected. The problem is that when using the callback, i'm not getting redirected back to my website, and so can't actually use the data.

Here is my googleStrategy:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import User from '../models/User';

const googleLogin = new GoogleStrategy(
  {
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL_DEV}${process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL}`,
    proxy: true,
  },
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
            // try to find user by googleId
      const user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
      if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // if here then no user found, create new user, then return it
    try {
      const newUser = await new User({
        provider: 'google',
        googleId: profile.id,
        username: `user${profile.id}`, // saves googleId as username: user1234567890
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        name: profile.displayName,
      }).save();
      done(null, newUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
);

passport.use(googleLogin);
```

Here is the response url from google callback, and the response on that url (If this data helps somehow):
http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0AfJohXkqG-Hv4H27yDa9NRxTv3SCyytau9ZbwwpEvNBp1ssh5x2O7JmzG0Apla9MpAr-lQ&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+openid&authuser=0&prompt=consent

```
{
    "accessToken": "accesTokenHere",
    "refreshToken": "refreshTokenHere",
    "userInfo": {
      "id": "65b2e6c7af1334087e7049fc",
      "provider": "google",
      "email": "example@email.com",
      "username": "user102015033027514482051",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "avatar": "images/default/default-avatar.png",
      "posts": [],
      "comments": [],
      "createdAt": "2024-01-25T22:55:03.616Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-01-25T22:55:03.616Z"
    }
}
```

I'm not using sessions. Instead I just have the timed tokens.

I've tried creating a seperate login method specifically for the google callback to use:

```
const loginWithGoogle = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const accessToken = req.user.generateJWT(); // req.user is set by passport
    const refreshToken = req.user.generateRefreshToken();
    const userInfo = req.user.toJSON();
    res.json({ accessToken, refreshToken, userInfo }).redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL_DEV);
};
```

But this doesn't work either, because I can't use both .json and .redirect after already setting the headers in .json.

I've also tried sending tokens and user information as query parameters, but that seems like the complete wrong way to do it and extremely bad practice as well as insecure.

I've got a lot of frontend that depends on the response having the body of { accessToken, refreshToken, userInfo } so I'd rather not start refactoring everything and keep that template.

Answer (score 1):

##### Overview:

This setup creates a Node.js application with Express, integrating Google OAuth for user authentication. User data is managed using MongoDB, and Passport.js handles user authentication and session management. The application includes routes for Google authentication and callbacks, storing authenticated user details in MongoDB.

##### Authorization Sequence with google

[image]

I am using Mongodb in local, and need to set up the Google Project

##### Prepare Steps

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/
```

#1 Create google project

[image]

#2 Create OAuth Client ID

[image]

#3 Save client_secret.json from Google Developer It will use a credential at python demo code

[image]

[image]

#4 Install Mongodb and create "users" collection and "users" database

[image]

#5 Install node.js dependencies

```bash
npm install express express-session passport passport-google-oauth20
```

##### Demo code

This code will work

Save as `google.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'client_secret.json');
const clientSecrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, 'utf8'));
const CLIENT_ID = clientSecrets.web.client_id;
const CLIENT_SECRET = clientSecrets.web.client_secret;
const REDIRECT_URI = clientSecrets.web.redirect_uris[0];

const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const mongoUri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/users';
const client = new MongoClient(mongoUri);

async function connectMongo() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Connected successfully to MongoDB");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

connectMongo();

// Configure Passport to use Google OAuth 2.0
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: REDIRECT_URI,
    proxy: true
},
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        try {
            const usersCollection = client.db("users").collection("users");
            const email = profile.emails && profile.emails.length > 0 ? profile.emails[0].value : null;
    
            let user = await usersCollection.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
    
            if (!user) {
                user = {
                    googleId: profile.id,
                    username: `user${profile.id}`,
                    email: email,
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    accessToken: accessToken,
                    refreshToken: refreshToken,
                    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
                    updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
                };
                const result = await usersCollection.insertOne(user);
                console.log("Inserted new user:", result);
            } else {
                // Update the existing user (if needed)
                // For example, you might want to update the access token
            }
    
            done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error in GoogleStrategy:", err);
            done(err, null);
        }
    }));

// Passport session setup
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.googleId);  // Storing user's Google ID in the session
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const usersCollection = client.db("users").collection("users");
        const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ googleId: id });
        done(null, user); // The user object is added to the request as req.user
    } catch (err) {
        done(err, null);
    }
});

const app = express();

// Configure Express session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'YourSessionSecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Define routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Home Page. Login with <a href="/auth/google">Google</a>');
});

app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email'],
        accessType: 'offline',  // Request offline access
        prompt: 'consent'       // Force consent screen to reissue refresh token
    })
);

app.get('/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user); // Log the user data

        const userProfile = req.user;

        const response = {
            accessToken: userProfile.accessToken,
            refreshToken: userProfile.refreshToken,
            userInfo: {
                id: userProfile.googleId,
                provider: 'google',
                email: userProfile.email || 'No email provided',
                username: userProfile.username || 'user undefined',
                name: userProfile.name,
                avatar: userProfile.avatar || 'default_avatar_url_here',
                posts: [], // Populate as required
                comments: [], // Populate as required
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
                updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
            }
        };

        res.json(response);
    });

// Using you redirect port #
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

##### Run it

```
node google.js
```

##### Access by Browser

```
http://locahost:3000
```

#1 Click this button

[image]

#2 Click you good ID

[image]

#3 Keep continue

[image]

[image]

##### Results

In Browser,
[image]

In terminal,
[image]

In Mongodb,
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I have something very similar to what you posted here. My main problem is what you posted in the first image in results, the browser part.
Why is the json response showing in the browser with the url localhost:3000/callback, and how can that be sent back to the client but also redirected?

How can the client side of the application get that response, and use it while keeping the UI as expected?

Comment: @Shakshouk, I added the "Authorization Sequence with google" diagram, It will help to understand of sequence.  Why is the json response showing in the browser? -> It shows to the user dubbing purpose. how can that be sent back to the client but also redirected?  -> Google Server redirect to backend ('/callback') with auth code, then passport handling to exchange code for token request. And Google server check valid it, if yes send the tokens/user information to the backend. How can client side of the application get that response->Client get information from the backend server by res.json()